# how to use regex as delimiter for stringtokenizer

Tags: java, regex

I want to retrieve the string between `|2~ and |`

What is the regex sequence to make this work?

Supposedly I have **|2~21381030213jafjs231|adfafafasdfas** And I am using

```
StringTokenizer test = new StringTokenizer(string, delim);
```

I tried 
    StringTokenizer(string, "//|/2/~%s/|") // doesn't work.

but it doesn't work.

Can you also elaborate how regex work (like how regex sequence works)? Or good link to start looking into.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need the Regex, `.*~(.*)\|` will do. And here is a [Regex 101 to prove it.](http://regex101.com/r/dC8nN5) Now, to explain the Regex, it's pretty simple:

- `.*` tells the engine to match all characters;
- `~` then tells the engine to stop when it finds a `~`;
- `(.*)` then tells the engine to match all characters and group them as a match;
- `\|` then finally tells the engine to match the `|` which will stop the grouping.

But to learn Regex, [have a look at this site](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html), it's one of the best on the web.

Comment: @user2698142, I did explain it as best I could. In order. But for you to get a better understanding have a look at the link I provided at the end of the answer. You need to learn Regex, and that's **way outside the scope** of this question.

Comment: `~ then tells the engine to stop when it finds a ~;` Given that you used a greedy quantifier for your `.`, it will `stop when it finds a ~`, but it searches from the back first.

Comment: @Cruncher, you are correct. It could be modified to be `.*?~` instead.

Comment: i have to say though that the website that teaches regex makes it even more confusing.

Comment: @JungJoo, it's actually one of the best resources on the web, but Regex isn't a simple language. Do some more searching, and if you find a better resource let me know.

Answer (score 3):

`StringTokenizer` does not support regex. You need to use the `Pattern` & `Matcher` classes

```
String  s = "|2~21381030213jafjs231|adfafafasdfas";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\|\\d~([^|]+)\\|").matcher(s);
if ( m.find() ) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Comment: oh really? i thought delimiter and regex were same thing

Comment: @user2698142, even if it doesn't support Regex, a Regex is what you need for this task. Splitting it on a token wouldn't be good enough. Or it would at least require some interesting sub stringing.

Comment: you think its easier to pass it into scanner? and use findinline(regex)?

Comment: `findInLine` will give you the full match not the group contents you have to modify the regex to use non look ahead+behind

Comment: really nice answer, can you explain what you did for the pattern? i dont understand ([^}]+). thanks.

Comment: `()` is used for capturing groups accessed via `m.group(1)`. `[]` is a character class and `^` is the not operator inside the character class so `[^|]+` means match all characters that are not `|`