# StringTokenizer use

Tags: java, file, stringtokenizer, zipcode

I am trying to use the StringTokenizer to set a comma as the delimiter with lines from a file, each consisting of a zipcode and city (e.x. 01221, Washington, DC), but I don't want the second comma to be a delimiter since it is part of the city name.  I have 2 classes in which I read in the zip code and city name, but I'm not sure how to correctly use the tokenizer to set the zip code and city apart.  I want to return 1 array of each the zip code and city from each class so I don't want to combine them into one class.  I am also not sure if I should put the tokenizer in my main method or not.

```
public static String[] getZipCodes (File zips, Scanner hi, int d)
{
    //creating array of zip codes with the length of the number of lines
    String[] zipCodes=new String[d];
    //Loops through each zip code to fill the array
    for (int i=0; i<d; i++)
    {
        zipCodes[i]=hi.next();
        System.out.println(zipCodes[i]);
    }
    return zipCodes;
}

public static String[] getCities (File zips, Scanner hi, int d)
{
    //creating array of cities
    String[] cities=new String[d];
    //fills array with city names, parallel to its zip code
    for (int i=0; i<d; i++)
    {
        hi.next();
        cities[i]=hi.next();
        hi.nextLine();
    }
    return cities;
}
```

Here is the main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File zips=new File("ZipCodesCity.txt");
    //Scanner to count number of lines in file
    Scanner in=new Scanner(zips);

    //Counting number of zip codes
    int codenum=0;
    while (in.hasNextLine())
    {
        codenum++;
    }

    //making a second scanner to read in the zip codes
    Scanner hi= new Scanner(zips);

    //initializing array of zip codes
    String[]zipCodes=getZipCodes(zips, hi, codenum);

    //Tokenizer
    StringTokenizer wrd=new StringTokenizer(hi.nextLine(), ",");
}
```

Comment: I added a close brace that seemed to be missing; if that was wrong, re-edit.  If it was correct, flag this comment obsolete.

Comment: If you need to split a string into two parts in all the cases, consider using String.indexOf() and String.substring(). Tokenizer is useful when amount of substring is not predicatable (btw, you can use String.split() to do the same operation).

Comment: I'm not sure how I could take the indexOf(0,4) for every line since I would have to say in.next() and indexOf

Answer (score 1):

A workaround solution to your problem would be to use a regular expression with the stringtokenizer.  You're only trying to split on the first comma, since the second comma is part of the city name.  Conveniently, the first comma *always* comes after number since a zip code is always a number, and the second comma *never* comes after a number because no city name contains any numbers.  Thus, your delimiter is any expression where there is a number followed by a comma.  You can reference [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852318/how-to-use-regex-as-delimiter-for-stringtokenizer) to see an example of using regex with stringtokenizer.

**EDIT**
More simply you could just take the substring consisting of the first 5 characters since every zip code is of length 5, and then the rest of the string is the city and state. This approach is much simpler

Comment: More simply you could just take the substring consisting of the first 5 characters since every zip code is of length 5, and then the rest of the string is the city and state.  This approach is much simpler